# Загрузка изображений как в ВК

Tags: jquery, вконтакте, изображения, fileupload

Как сделать загрузку изображения на страницу как на сайте ВКонтакте? То есть, чтобы, когда вы выбираете файл и нажимаете "готово", он сразу показывался на странице. Интересует, как это сделать, используя только jQuery.

Comment: Он заливается в начале на сервер, а потом возвращает ссылку на сервере.... и просто показываете `img` с `src` который вернул сервер

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Заливается через jquery?

Comment: Идет отправка через `ajax` на сервер.... сервер обрабатывает и складывает в БД.... сервер может быть написан на чем угодно: php, nodejs,java, c# ...что взбредtт в голову

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Щас буду чтото думать/искать. А Вам спасибо

Comment: Еще как вариант не загружать сразу на сервер а предварительно отобразить `preview` и если юзер нажал `опубликовать` то уже делать те вещи о которых я написал........ для превью можно воспользоваться html5 и его `FileReader` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader  ...... вот кстати пример для вас http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/